# Prove that $(A+B)^n = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ real matrices such that $A^n = B^n = 0$ and $AB = BA$. Prove that $(A+B)^n = 0$.

We have $$(A+B)^n = A^n+A^{n-1}B\binom{n}{1}+\cdots+AB^{n-1}\binom{n}{n-1}+B^n.$$ I tried proving this for just the case $n = 2$. We have $(A+B)^2 = A^2+2AB+B^2 = 2AB$ since $A^2 = B^2 = 0$. Then I didn't see how to show that $AB = 0$.

Answer (score 9):

Since $A$ and $B$ commute, they can be simultaneously triangularized over $\mathbb{C}$. In other words, there exists an invertible matrix $P$ and upper-triangular matrices $T$ and $U$ such that
$$ T=P^{-1}AP $$
and
$$U=P^{-1}BP $$
Moreover, since 
$$ T^n=P^{-1}A^nP=0 $$
it follows that $T$ must be strictly upper triangular (i.e. it has no non-zero entries on its diagonal), and similarly $U$ must be strictly upper triangular as well.

Therefore $T+U$ is strictly upper triangular, so $(T+U)^n=0$, hence
$$ (A+B)^n=P(T+U)^nP^{-1}=0 $$

Comment: Hi carmichael561, can you guide us in the next please https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2440926/measurable-functions-and-existence-decreasing-function

Answer (score 6):

If you expand $(A+B)^{2n}$ with the binomial theorem, you'll see that $A^n=B^n=0$ implies each term is $0$ because each term has $A^j B^k$ where either $j\geq n$ or $k\geq n$.  Hence $A+B$ is a nilpotent matrix.  [If $C$ is an $n$-by-$n$ nilpotent matrix, then $C^n=0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108422/how-to-show-that-the-nth-power-of-a-nxn-nilpotent-matrix-equals-to-zero-an-0/108424)

Comment: Can you explain how each term is $0$?

Comment: They look like some constant times $A^j B^k$ with $j+k=2n$, so $j\geq n$ or $k\geq n$, with implies $A^j=0$ or $B^k=0$.  (Really $2n-1$ would suffice.)

Comment: How does it imply $A^j = 0$ or $B^k = 0$?

Comment: @user19405892: If $j\geq n$, then $A^j = A^n A^{j-n}=0\cdot A^{j-n}=0$.  Similarly, if $k\geq n$, then $B^k=0$.  E.g., if $A^{32}=0$, then also $A^{37}=A^{32}A^5=0$.