# If for linear operator $A:E\to E$, $A^k=0$, then $A^n=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let for the linear operator $A:E\to E$, $A^k=0$, then $A^n=0$.

Here $n=dim E$ and $n <k.$

I tried to find the characteristic oolynomial that I think it is the clue, however did nit succeed.

Any suggestion?

Comment: If $A^k=0$, the minimal polynomial of $A$ is equal to some $X^m$ and it shares the same roots as the characteristic polynomial, so the characteristic polynomial is $X^n$.

Comment: Do you know the Cayley-Hamilton theorem?

Comment: This could help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108422/how-to-show-that-the-nth-power-of-a-n-times-n-nilpotent-matrix-equals-to-zero.

Comment: I know Cayley -Hamilton. Wrt the first comment the roots are zero and so it is solved! yes?